# Mysql DB viewer user (only for views) should access to information_schema and test?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, permissions

I've created a user in our mysql/mariaDB engine so our customers can read some views. User has been created as follows and can query the views with no problem.

```
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS "user_viewer"@"%" IDENTIFIED BY "password";
...
GRANT SELECT ON mydb.my_view1 TO 'user_viewer'@'%';
GRANT SELECT ON mydb.my_view2 TO 'user_viewer'@'%';
```

However, I'm wondering that this user has full read access to "information_schema" and "test" schemas. I understand that first is a dynamically built table necessary for normal usage but I don't understand why it has access to "test" (created automatically by mariaDB during deployment), even when I revoke all privileges with

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES, GRANT OPTION FROM 'iristrace_viewer'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: In some versions, a wildcard user is granted privileges to schemas matching `'test%'` so any user implicitly has access to any schema name starting with test. I don't have MariaDB, but I think you can try checking: `SELECT * FROM mysql.db WHERE db LIKE 'test%'`

Comment: thanks @BillKarwin to point me in the right direction, I will add a comment explaining the issue

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @BillKarwin to point me in the right direction.

[image]

This can be done running https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_secure_installation/

Comment: Recent versions of MySQL have decided not to create a 'test' schema or the privileges to all users for that schema by default, for the reason of security.